# Fetch the data that was submitted in the google form (using OnFormSubmit trigger) with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I created an apps script project for my google form, and added a trigger which has the following settigs -

[image]

and my Code.gs file has this code, which is supposed to execute when a new submission arrives -

```
function sendemail(e) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("sampleemail@gmail.com","Hello there","This is a sample sentence.");
}
```

When I tested this trigger by submitting a new form, I received the test email successfully. Now instead of a static email (sampleemail@gmail.com) being used as the recipient of the email, I want it to be the value my user entered in the Email field in the form submission which triggered this function. So I want my code to look like -

```
function sendemail(e) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("<email from form response>","Hello <name from the form>","This is a sample sentence.");
}
```

So if the trigger data is arriving in the `e` parameter in `sendemail` function, how do I get the data which was submitted? When I debugged JSON.stringify(e), I get `{"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"12647267"}`.

Is there any way I get the data that was submitted in the form in the function? Do I need to change any settings on my form or trigger to get the data? I've just started with Google Apps Script and am a bit confused on how should I do this... Any advice is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Try using the onFormSubmit trigger for the linked Spreadsheet.  It;s event object contains namedValues and values.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, I now get the data in `namedValues` parameter in the `e` json. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @Cooper in the comments

---

> Try using the onFormSubmit trigger for the linked Spreadsheet. It;s event object contains namedValues and values.

Thanks @Cooper, it works perfectly now. Cheers!